# Subrotas em Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, route

Estou com a seguinte dúvida.

Tenho duas rotas GET, sendo que a segunda rota, sempre que tento acessar, o browser entende como se estivesse informando o parâmetro *:id* e gera um erro.

```
routes.get('/tasks/:id', TaskController.show);
routes.get('/tasks/pending', TaskController.pendingTasks);
```

Tem alguma forma de contornar isso, sem que eu altere o resource */tasks* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Express verifica as rotas pela ordem em que foram registadas, e a primeira que verificar a condição recebe a ligação. Ou seja, ele vai verifica `tasks/:id` primeiro e sendo que `/:id` é generalista ele vai ignorar `/pending`.

Há duas soluções, a mais simples é trocar a ordem. Regista `/pending` primeiro.

```
routes.get('/tasks/pending', TaskController.pendingTasks);
routes.get('/tasks/:id', TaskController.show);
```

A segunda é chamar `TaskController.pendingTasks` dentro de `TaskController.show`, ou pelo menos desse `/tasks/:id`... por exemplo:

```
routes.get('/tasks/:id', (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  if (id === 'pending'){
    TaskController.show
  } else {
    TaskController.pendingTasks
  }
});
```